# Initialize object once for all test cases

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestcase

In the following bit of code `appSettings` variable initializes for every test case. How to make it initialize once for the whole test class? Using singleton would be a problem if it is used for several test classes when you run them together at once, because it will be initialized once for all test classes

```
final class TestsmthTests: XCTestCase {
        
        var appSettings = AppSettings()
    
        override func setUpWithError() throws {
    
        }
    
        func testExample() throws {
            
        }
        
        func testMore() throws {
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want this? What is it about AppSettings that you want to share one instance across test cases, rather than having each test make its own?

Answer (score 1):

Make it a static variable of your `XCTestCase` class.

```
final class TestsmthTests: XCTestCase {
        
        static var appSettings = AppSettings()
    
        override func setUpWithError() throws {
    
        }
    
        func testExample() throws {

            var foo = TestsmthTests.appSettings.someProperty()  
        }
        
        func testMore() throws {
            var foo = TestsmthTests.appSettings.someProperty()              
        }
    }
```

I'd be reluctant to do this though because, the tests are meant to be independent and so, if you modify `appSettings` in a test, you may start seeing issues.